# how to draw a 3D angle in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 3d, draw, angle

I have three angles who's values are 0.0 , 94.3750 , -0.5625.
Starting from those 3 angles, how can I draw an 3D angle in MATLAB?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think we need a bit more information about what you're trying to do. Are those angles the X, Y, and Z rotations? If so, that will give you a vector in 3D space. How do you want to represent that vector?

Comment: I have over 5000 values of the three Euler angle pitch roll and yaw. I would like to present these angles in Matlab to determine the movement.

Comment: I still don't know *how* you want to present these angles. Do you want to display each one as a vector from the origin? Do you want to rotate a known point through these angles and display that? Do you want to display the vectors representing the change in positions of that fixed point between each rotation? What type of projection do you want from 3D onto 2D? From what viewpoint?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post an image or diagram showing what you're trying to do.

Comment: the main idea is to get the movement progressing.. I have a sensor attached to a chair that moves, then the sensor collect the three Euler angles.. So maybe if I display the vectors representing the change in positions of that fixed point between each rotation, I will get a clear idea of the chair movement. Thanks

Comment: If your question is how do you visualize your sensor data, that is probably beyond the scope of Stack Overflow. For one thing, it would be opinion-based since you might prefer to visualize the data one way, and someone else might wish to see it another way. If you have specific points you want to plot at specific rotations and you need help coding it, that's more in line with the types of questions that Stack Overflow can answer.

Comment: Normally people just use plots of each euler angle vs. time. Here's [an option for visualization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zSY07bw6J0) as well, with source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
angles=abs(pi/2*rand(3,50)); %data
figure
for ii=1:size(angles,2)
quiver3(0,0,0,cos(angles(1,ii)),cos(angles(2,ii)),cos(angles(3,ii))) %plot arrow
view(30,30) %or Matlab will choose it arbitrarily
axis([0 1 0 1 0 1]) %just for convenience
pause(.2)
end
```

and if you want to save the figures in order:

```
angles=abs(pi/2*rand(3,50));
figure(1)
for ii=1:size(angles,2)
quiver3(0,0,0,cos(angles(1,ii)),cos(angles(2,ii)),cos(angles(3,ii)))
view(30,30)
axis([0 1 0 1 0 1])
pause(.2)
file_name= sprintf('%0.4d_%s_%s',ll);
print('-f1',file_name,'-dpng')
close(1)
end
```